# Handling Unicode in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I write a small program to get location information using MKReverseGeocoder.
The return is like :

Country = "\U53f0\U6e7e";
CountryCode = TW;

I know this is unicode, but any function in iPhone SDK help convert this to readable string?

Comment: Ahh, I got my problem. I output the whole array so the unicode is represented as \U53f0\U6e7e. They are already there. Just output each one then every thing goes OK.

Comment: hi, answer your own question and mark your answer as accepted; then people reading it will know you solved it ;)